# Tensorflow object detection api Windows fatal exception: access violation, step stayed at 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

Trying to train custom object detection model following this tutorial:
https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
I have also tested a different dataset with different model from here:
https://github.com/TannerGilbert/Tensorflow-Object-Detection-API-Train-Model
but both return the same problem.
All my directory structures follows the first tutorial.

OS: Windows 10
CUDA: 11.3
Tensorflow: 2.5.0
Python: 3.9

Log:

```
2021-06-12 20:17:36.619265: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1258] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-06-12 20:17:36.619301: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1264]      0 
2021-06-12 20:17:36.619309: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1277] 0:   N 
2021-06-12 20:17:36.619452: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1418] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 2145 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 with Max-Q Design, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
WARNING:tensorflow:Collective ops is not configured at program startup. Some performance features may not be enabled.
W0612 20:17:36.634464 11076 mirrored_strategy.py:379] Collective ops is not configured at program startup. Some performance features may not be enabled.
INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0',)
I0612 20:17:36.728192 11076 mirrored_strategy.py:369] Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0',)
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting train_steps: None
I0612 20:17:36.728192 11076 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting train_steps: None
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
I0612 20:17:36.728192 11076 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py:557: StrategyBase.experimental_distribute_datasets_from_function (from tensorflow.python.distribute.distribute_lib) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
rename to distribute_datasets_from_function
W0612 20:17:36.744960 11076 deprecation.py:330] From C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py:557: StrategyBase.experimental_distribute_datasets_from_function (from tensorflow.python.distribute.distribute_lib) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
rename to distribute_datasets_from_function
INFO:tensorflow:Reading unweighted datasets: ['annotations/train.record']
I0612 20:17:36.760623 11076 dataset_builder.py:163] Reading unweighted datasets: ['annotations/train.record']
INFO:tensorflow:Reading record datasets for input file: ['annotations/train.record']
I0612 20:17:36.760623 11076 dataset_builder.py:80] Reading record datasets for input file: ['annotations/train.record']
INFO:tensorflow:Number of filenames to read: 1
I0612 20:17:36.760623 11076 dataset_builder.py:81] Number of filenames to read: 1
WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
W0612 20:17:36.760623 11076 dataset_builder.py:87] num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py:101: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.experimental_deterministic`.
W0612 20:17:36.760623 11076 deprecation.py:330] From C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py:101: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.experimental_deterministic`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py:236: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
W0612 20:17:36.776248 11076 deprecation.py:330] From C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py:236: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:206: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
W0612 20:17:42.585761 11076 deprecation.py:330] From C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:206: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:206: sample_distorted_bounding_box (from tensorflow.python.ops.image_ops_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
`seed2` arg is deprecated.Use sample_distorted_bounding_box_v2 instead.
W0612 20:17:45.209203 11076 deprecation.py:330] From C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:206: sample_distorted_bounding_box (from tensorflow.python.ops.image_ops_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
`seed2` arg is deprecated.Use sample_distorted_bounding_box_v2 instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py:464: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
W0612 20:17:46.765527 11076 deprecation.py:330] From C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py:464: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
2021-06-12 20:17:49.246970: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:176] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py:435: UserWarning: `tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase` is deprecated and will be removed after 2020-10-11. To update it, simply pass a True/False value to the `training` argument of the `__call__` method of your layer or model.
  warnings.warn('`tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase` is deprecated and '
2021-06-12 20:18:20.053992: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-06-12 20:18:20.578938: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:359] Loaded cuDNN version 8201
2021-06-12 20:18:21.387817: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:271] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 934.75MiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2021-06-12 20:18:21.387940: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:271] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 934.75MiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2021-06-12 20:18:21.605687: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-06-12 20:18:22.316327: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-06-12 20:18:22.544715: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:271] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.54GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2021-06-12 20:18:22.544804: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:271] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.54GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2021-06-12 20:18:22.680473: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:271] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 916.00MiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2021-06-12 20:18:22.680578: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:271] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 916.00MiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2021-06-12 20:18:22.680686: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:271] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.54GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2021-06-12 20:18:22.680753: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:271] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.54GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2021-06-12 20:18:33.129542: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:456] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 400.00MiB (rounded to 419430400)requested by op ResNet50V1_FPN/model/conv2_block2_3_bn/FusedBatchNormV3
If the cause is memory fragmentation maybe the environment variable 'TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR=cuda_malloc_async' will improve the situation. 
Current allocation summary follows.
Current allocation summary follows.
2021-06-12 20:18:33.129852: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:991] BFCAllocator dump for GPU_0_bfc
2021-06-12 20:18:33.130006: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:998] Bin (256):   Total Chunks: 77, Chunks in use: 77. 19.2KiB allocated for chunks. 19.2KiB in use in bin. 8.7KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2021-06-12 20:18:33.130118: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:998] Bin (512):   Total Chunks: 94, Chunks in use: 81. 47.0KiB allocated for chunks. 40.5KiB in use in bin. 35.3KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2021-06-12 20:18:33.130229: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:998] Bin (1024):  Total Chunks: 263, Chunks in use: 261. 276.2KiB allocated for chunks. 274.0KiB in use in bin. 271.0KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2021-06-12 20:18:33.130329: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:998] Bin (2048):  Total Chunks: 65, Chunks in use: 61. 134.5KiB allocated for chunks. 123.2KiB in use in bin. 121.5KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2021-06-12 20:18:33.130427: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:998] Bin (4096):  Total Chunks: 32, Chunks in use: 31. 135.5KiB allocated for chunks. 130.8KiB in use in bin. 130.8KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2021-06-12 20:18:33.130529: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:998] Bin (8192):  Total Chunks: 16, Chunks in use: 16. 134.0KiB allocated for chunks. 134.0KiB in use in bin. 128.0KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2021-06-12 20:18:33.130631: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:998] Bin (16384):     Total Chunks: 5, Chunks in use: 4. 131.0KiB allocated for chunks. 103.0KiB in use in bin. 91.0KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2021-06-12 20:18:33.130732: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:998] Bin (32768):     Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 1. 36.8KiB allocated for chunks. 36.8KiB in use in bin. 36.8KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2021-06-12 20:18:33.130829: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:998] Bin (65536):     Total Chunks: 8, Chunks in use: 6. 561.0KiB allocated for chunks. 416.0KiB in use in bin. 384.0KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2021-06-12 20:18:33.130929: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:998] Bin (131072):    Total Chunks: 7, Chunks in use: 7. 1.13MiB allocated for chunks. 1.13MiB in use in bin. 1.13MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2021-06-12 20:18:33.131026: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:998] Bin (262144):    Total Chunks: 11, Chunks in use: 9. 3.10MiB allocated for chunks. 2.44MiB in use in bin. 2.16MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2021-06-12 20:18:33.131123: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:998] Bin (524288):    Total Chunks: 11, Chunks in use: 10. 6.41MiB allocated for chunks. 5.91MiB in use in bin. 5.57MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2021-06-12 20:18:33.131222: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:998] Bin (1048576):   Total Chunks: 13, Chunks in use: 12. 14.22MiB allocated for chunks. 13.00MiB in use in bin. 12.00MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2021-06-12 20:18:33.131321: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:998] Bin (2097152):   Total Chunks: 24, Chunks in use: 21. 55.75MiB allocated for chunks. 48.75MiB in use in bin. 46.50MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2021-06-12 20:18:33.131698: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:998] Bin (4194304):   Total Chunks: 21, Chunks in use: 21. 98.05MiB allocated for chunks. 98.05MiB in use in bin. 98.05MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2021-06-12 20:18:33.131835: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:998] Bin (8388608):   Total Chunks: 5, Chunks in use: 5. 50.61MiB allocated for chunks. 50.61MiB in use in bin. 50.61MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2021-06-12 20:18:33.131939: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:998] Bin (16777216):  Total Chunks: 18, Chunks in use: 18. 348.91MiB allocated for chunks. 348.91MiB in use in bin. 344.19MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2021-06-12 20:18:33.132030: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:998] Bin (33554432):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2021-06-12 20:18:33.132129: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:998] Bin (67108864):  Total Chunks: 3, Chunks in use: 1. 270.09MiB allocated for chunks. 75.00MiB in use in bin. 75.00MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2021-06-12 20:18:33.132223: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:998] Bin (134217728):     Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 0. 136.58MiB allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2021-06-12 20:18:33.132325: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:998] Bin (268435456):     Total Chunks: 3, Chunks in use: 2. 1.13GiB allocated for chunks. 821.95MiB in use in bin. 800.00MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2021-06-12 20:18:33.132408: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1014] Bin for 400.00MiB was 256.00MiB, Chunk State: 
2021-06-12 20:18:33.132526: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1020]   Size: 337.16MiB | Requested Size: 19.51MiB | in_use: 0 | bin_num: 20, prev:   Size: 4.88MiB | Requested Size: 4.88MiB | in_use: 1 | bin_num: -1, for: Loss/Compare_10/IOU/Equal, stepid: 16762585343613708217, last_action: 126448115942167, for: UNUSED, stepid: 16762585343613708217, last_action: 126448115942071
2021-06-12 20:18:33.132604: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1027] Next region of size 2249614848
2021-06-12 20:18:33.132724: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0b000000 of size 1280 by op ScratchBuffer action_count 126448115939866 step 0 next 1


...


2021-06-12 20:18:33.136180: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0fbe1700 of size 1024 by op Fill action_count 126448115940507 step 0 next 341
2021-06-12 20:18:33.136188: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0fbe1b00 of size 1024 by op Fill action_count 126448115940508 step 0 next 342
2021-06-12 20:18:33.136196: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0fbe1f00 of size 1024 by op Fill action_count 126448115940514 step 0 next 344
2021-06-12 20:18:33.136204: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0fbe2300 of size 1024 by op Fill action_count 126448115940515 step 0 next 345
2021-06-12 20:18:33.136212: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0fbe2700 of size 1024 by op Fill action_count 126448115940516 step 0 next 346
2021-06-12 20:18:33.136220: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0fbe2b00 of size 1024 by op Fill action_count 126448115940517 step 0 next 347
2021-06-12 20:18:33.136228: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0fbe2f00 of size 1024 by op Fill action_count 126448115940523 step 0 next 349
2021-06-12 20:18:33.136237: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0fbe3300 of size 1024 by op Fill action_count 126448115940524 step 0 next 350
2021-06-12 20:18:33.136245: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0fbe3700 of size 1024 by op Fill action_count 126448115940525 step 0 next 351
2021-06-12 20:18:33.136253: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0fbe3b00 of size 1024 by op Fill action_count 126448115940526 step 0 next 352
2021-06-12 20:18:33.136261: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0fbe3f00 of size 256 by op Fill action_count 126448115940532 step 0 next 353
2021-06-12 20:18:33.136268: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0fbe4000 of size 1024 by op Fill action_count 126448115940538 step 0 next 354
2021-06-12 20:18:33.136277: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0fbe4400 of size 1024 by op Fill action_count 126448115940539 step 0 next 355
2021-06-12 20:18:33.136286: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0fbe4800 of size 1024 by op Fill action_count 126448115940540 step 0 next 356
2021-06-12 20:18:33.136295: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0fbe4c00 of size 1024 by op Fill action_count 126448115940541 step 0 next 357
2021-06-12 20:18:33.136304: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0fbe5000 of size 1024 by op Fill action_count 126448115940547 step 0 next 359
2021-06-12 20:18:33.136312: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0fbe5400 of size 1024 by op Fill action_count 126448115940548 step 0 next 360
2021-06-12 20:18:33.136320: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0fbe5800 of size 1024 by op Fill action_count 126448115940549 step 0 next 361
2021-06-12 20:18:33.136328: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0fbe5c00 of size 1024 by op Fill action_count 126448115940550 step 0 next 362
2021-06-12 20:18:33.136336: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0fbe6000 of size 1024 by op Fill action_count 126448115940556 step 0 next 364
2021-06-12 20:18:33.136344: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0fbe6400 of size 1024 by op Fill action_count 126448115940557 step 0 next 365
2021-06-12 20:18:33.136352: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0fbe6800 of size 1024 by op Fill action_count 126448115940558 step 0 next 366
2021-06-12 20:18:33.136360: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0fbe6c00 of size 1024 by op Fill action_count 126448115940559 step 0 next 367
2021-06-12 20:18:33.136368: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0fbe7000 of size 1024 by op Fill action_count 126448115940565 step 0 next 369
2021-06-12 20:18:33.136377: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0fbe7400 of size 1024 by op Fill action_count 126448115940566 step 0 next 370
2021-06-12 20:18:33.136385: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0fbe7800 of size 1024 by op Fill action_count 126448115940567 step 0 next 371
2021-06-12 20:18:33.136393: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] InUse at b0fbe7c00 of size 1024 by op Fill action_count 126448115940568 step 0 next 372
Windows fatal exception: access violation

Thread 0x000056c4 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 576 in _handle_results
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\threading.py", line 892 in run
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\threading.py", line 954 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\threading.py", line 912 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x000038f4 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 528 in _handle_tasks
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\threading.py", line 892 in run
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\threading.py", line 954 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\threading.py", line 912 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x0000275c (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 816 in _exhaustive_wait
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 884 in wait
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 499 in _wait_for_updates
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 519 in _handle_workers
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\threading.py", line 892 in run
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\threading.py", line 954 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\threading.py", line 912 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00004788 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 114 in worker
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\threading.py", line 892 in run
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\threading.py", line 954 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\threading.py", line 912 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00002b44 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 59 in quick_execute
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 591 in call
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1960 in _call_flat
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3023 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 950 in _call
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 889 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\mirrored_run.py", line 86 in call_for_each_replica
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\mirrored_strategy.py", line 678 in _call_for_each_replica
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py", line 2833 in call_for_each_replica
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py", line 1285 in run
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 173 in _ensure_model_is_built
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 394 in load_fine_tune_checkpoint
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 599 in train_loop
  File "C:\Users\Edward\Projects\Tensorflow\workspace\training_demo\model_main_tf2.py", line 106 in main
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251 in _run_main
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 303 in run
  File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 40 in run
  File "C:\Users\Edward\Projects\Tensorflow\workspace\training_demo\model_main_tf2.py", line 115 in <module>
```

Comment: I got the same problem, still haven't figured out how to solve it

Comment: What is your batch size? Can you try with `8` and let us know?